# Wireshark verify_tools fails with "No such file or directory"

Tags: windows, build, wireshark

I am having problems running `verify_tools` to make a Wireshark build on Windows.  The makefile fails with the following errors about not being able to find a file.

```
C:\Development\wireshark>nmake -f Makefile.nmake verify_tools

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.40219.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

tools/win64-setup.sh: line 12: /cygdrive/c/Development/wireshark/tools/win-setup: No such file or directory
tools/win64-setup.sh: line 12: exec: /cygdrive/c/Development/wireshark/tools/win: cannot execute: No such file or directory
tools/win64-setup.sh: line 12: /cygdrive/c/Development/wireshark/tools/win-setup: No such file or directory
tools/win64-setup.sh: line 12: exec: /cygdrive/c/Development/wireshark/tools/win: cannot execute: No such file or directory
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\Users\indiv\apps\cygwin\bin\bash.EXE' : return code '0x7e'
Stop.
```

To debug, I changed win64-setup.sh and made it print `WIN_SETUP`.

```
echo WIN_SETUP: [$WIN_SETUP]
exec $WIN_SETUP $@
```

The results were bizarre.  Possibly because of some end-of-line issue.

```
C:\Development\wireshark>nmake -f Makefile.nmake verify_tools

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.40219.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

]IN_SETUP: [tools/win-setup.sh
```

How can I fix or work around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Wireshark build relies on all its supporting utilities coming from cygwin, except for `cl`, `link`, and `nmake`.  Your path is set up such that some supporting utilities are coming from elsewhere in your environment.  Like from an install of gnuwin32 or something.

For explanation purposes, let's say the variable `CYGWIN` is set to your cygwin path, like `c:\cygwin\bin`.

You are probably doing something like this, as suggested by the Wireshark wiki:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;%CYGWIN%
call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\SetEnv.Cmd" /Release /x64
```

Instead of doing it that way, move cygwin earlier in the path search order so that executables always come from there.  Then set up your Windows build environment so that Microsoft's `link` comes before cygwin's `link`.

```
set PATH=%CYGWIN%;%PATH%
call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\SetEnv.Cmd" /Release /x64
```

Don't forget when you make these changes to restart your shell to wipe the old environment completely because `SetEnv.cmd` may have cached the old environment, which will prevent you from changing `%PATH%`.

And then you get this instead when you run the verify_tools rule:

```
c:\Development\wireshark>nmake -f Makefile.nmake verify_tools

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.40219.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Checking for required applications:
        cl: /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/Bin/cl
        link: /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/Bin/link
        nmake: /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/Bin/nmake
        bash: /usr/bin/bash
        bison: /usr/bin/bison
        flex: /usr/bin/flex
        env: /usr/bin/env
        grep: /usr/bin/grep
        /usr/bin/find: /usr/bin/find
        peflags: /usr/bin/peflags
        perl: /usr/bin/perl
        sed: /usr/bin/sed
        unzip: /usr/bin/unzip
        wget: /usr/bin/wget
```